# How to display your own name in publications list when you are a middle-author on a publication with a large number of authors?

Tags: citations, formatting

My Name is among tens of authors of a paper on global health.

For the purpose of my CV update, I need to show my name without showing the names of all authors of the paper.

My preferred style is JAMA, which shows the names of the first 3 authors followed by 'et al'.

Would the following format be appropriate, at least for my CV, when My Name is published in the middle of a long authors' list ?

First Author, Co-Author, My Name, et al

If so, will this (customized) format ever cause any confusion for any group of audience?

Comment: I typically see people list all the authors and bold their own to make it easy to find in the list. I don't see a reason for hiding the other authors since page length for a CV shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.                  FYI, I have been lucky to have a last name which starts with A.  For now, in my updated CV, I have used this (customized) style:                                           First Author, Co-Authors, My Name, et al.

Comment: Just out of curiosity; Why do you need to show your name in the CV? If a paper is listed under publications, it should be clear that et al includes you.

Answer (score 38):

The bolding trick suggested by others is fine up to a point, but eventually it will get to be silly.

I'm coming from a nuclear and particle physics background and have papers with hundreds of coauthors. So I *didn't* take care that my name showed up. I just built my publication list using bibtex in the standard format for my discipline and assumed that readers who wanted to check that I was on those papers know how to use InSpire (the go-to publication database for these disciplines).

That means that my name appears on my publication list only a few times, but it is also there in big letters at the top of the page.

Comment: This is a good point. If it is in your list of publications, well, you are an author, and the actual positions beyond second are usually not so relevant.

Comment: unless you are faculty ... then last is relevant as well. In some fields it signals the PI.

Answer (score 33):

If I understand correctly you suggest adding your name as third regardless of where it occurs (later than third). I would not recommend such a solution since it may be thought of as inflating your own importance (assuming author order reflects that). Even if such a solution would be acceptable within a specific community, one has to consider how it can be construed by others. In my CV I have set my name in bold face and I list all author names in a reference. This way my "contribution" becomes reasonably clear even at a glance.

Comment: maybe im misunderstanding, but what happens with the papers that have over 100 author names, maybe in physics for example.  Would you list all of them?

Comment: Yes, consortia papers and papers with very large numbers of authors may be a specific problem. There are no patented solutions but one is perhaps, and only as a suggestion, to use a format like: "Smith and 41 others (*My Name*, author number 35)" or something along those lines. Where one draws the line is arbitrary and probably depends on the number of such papers in ones publication list.