# Ordering of co-primary authors on website

Tags: authorship, website

If a published paper had an author ordering [A,B] where A and B are primary authors and the ordering is alphabetical is it acceptable for B to list on his website the ordering [B,A] so his first-authorship would look more obvious to people skimming his website?

Comment: I would suggest **formatting your name in bold** to make it stand out. Also, I have seen people format their publications on their webpages by projects. I know these suggestions to not directly answer your question, but I think either one would help to make your own first authorship stand out more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [Can co-first authors’ positions be swapped in a CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38489/11365), the [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/38498/11365) with the most upvotes says

> No. The reference is the reference, changing it to move yourself higher could be misinterpreted as willful deceit.

I believe the same logic applies to a website.

However, in a website, you do have more freedom in style and formatting than you would in a CV (although you still don't have the freedom to change author order...) For example, if you want to call attention to first authorship, you could list first authors and co-first authors in a slightly different weight or different color than the other authors.