# How to list a paper in your CV when having 1000 co-authors?

Tags: citations, cv

This is a follow up to [the question *What is the point of listing 1000 authors for a single scientific paper?*](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63440/what-is-the-point-of-listing-1000-authors-for-a-single-scientific-paper), I'm just curious.

Supposed I were the 900th co-author in a paper with 1000 authors. How should I list this paper in my CV? Obviously, I don't want to use 3 pages of my CV just to list the details of a single paper.

Comment: FirstAuthor, N. et al ?

Comment: Earlier incarnation of this question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26802/how-to-display-your-own-name-in-publications-list-when-you-are-a-middle-author-o

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The quick answer might be to look up the CV of a CERN researcher...

From outside physics, when compiling institutional publication lists, I've occasionally dealt with a 100+ author entry (often a major report rather than a paper, but the same problem holds). As our motive for listing this is to note the local author(s), it's a similar situation to the CV.

In this case, I tend to do something like:

> Able, J., Anderson, M., Archer, C., [and 78 others, including **Smith, Q.**] (2015) A very tedious paper, *J. Irrep. Res.* 243(54)

or

> Able, J., Anderson, M., Archer, C., [et al, including **Smith, Q.**] (2015) A very tedious paper, *J. Irrep. Res.* 243(54)

where Q. Smith is the local author we care about. It's probably not a very theoretically sound citation style, but it seems to work!

Comment: Personally, I think the "and 78 others" approach for major reports, because the "et al" doesn't convey if there are lots of others co-authors or just a few more. Also, I've already seen it once or twice in a CV.

Comment: @gaborous Yes, I think I'd agree it's a bit clearer that way.

Comment: +1 for the citation of *J. Irrep. Res.* but note that it has been succeeded by *Ann. Improb. Res.*

Comment: "Theoretical soundness" of citation styles?

Comment: @immibis some people are very concerned about Sticking Exactly To A Platonically Correct Style, and I'm sure this approach is technically invalid in most of them :-)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to create citations in this format using bibtex or biblatex?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni no idea, sorry - we are technologically backward here and do it by hand :-)

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm new to the academic world and I don't understand that. Seems to be something like a joke. Could you explain me, please?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I bet it's possible with biblatex at least; it's very configurable. It's not immediately obvious from the documentation how one would do it, though. Perhaps you should ask on [tex.SE].

Comment: @rpax: [*Journal of Irreproducible Results*](http://www.jir.com/) is/was  a parody of scientific journals, publishing articles similar in form to scientific papers but with humorous content. It still exists, but after a schism in 1994, many of the editorial staff of *JIR* left to form [*Annals of Improbable Research*](http://www.improbable.com/), which now focuses on reporting on real scientific research that happens to be funny.

Answer (score 18):

In addition to the approach given by @Andrew, many journals will now push you toward an "consortium" authorship listing that simplifies the CV statement.  In this style, all but a few distinguished authors are listed as a consortium, whose members are specified elsewhere.  Thus:

> - Frankenstein, V., Jeckyll, A., Moreau, D., and the Parahuman Genetics Consortium (1898), Sequence of the Morlock Genome, J. Mad Sci., 10(3).
>     *(Member of Parahuman Genetics Consortium)*

Comment: What if you are not a permanent member of the PHGC? I.e., one of our students (Computer Science) did a two-month internship at CERN, and so became a coauthor of a physics paper, being involved in streamlining data analysis for an instrument.

Comment: @vonbrand When listing a consortium authorship, you are not referring to an external site, but to a list elsewhere (e.g., in the acknowledgements) that documents all the consortium members to be credited as authors.  Thus, a person may be a consortium author on one paper, but not on another paper from the "same" consortium.

Comment: How should one implement this in a CV?

Comment: @TommiBrander Just like I showed in my example.

Comment: So, you would not have the members listed elsewhere in a CV? That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

What I do is use either `Smith J et al. (2012), Journal of Awesomeness, 5(3)` or `The Whatever Consortium (2012), Journal of Awesomeness, 5(3)`.

My reasoning is that people understand that if it is on my CV then I am an author and the specific order/amount of authors is not important (given that I am not first or last). I have never run into any issues with this approach.

Comment: I think in some fields second author > third author > ... (In my field, they're all equal, thankfully!)

Comment: @Kimball I am confident that in no field is there a noticeable difference in importance between author 90 and author 900. I would be surprised if last author matters for these massive consortia.

Comment: In some fields, last author=the one who got the funding!

Comment: @GEdgar @Kimball if the author is sufficiently close to the start she could be listed by name, and the same goes for the end (e.g. `Smith J, ..., Frost R (2012)`).

Answer (score 2):

I am a member of a big collaboration.  The collaboration produces both "whole author list" papers for key results and "short author list" papers written by a subset of members.

In my CV I have a separate section for "selected full author list" publications, where I only list those to which I feel I have contributed directly.

> A. Aardvark, et al [Super Science Collaboration, including **P. Myself**]. *Observing stuff and taking names*. J. Rad Sci. 12(98) 2016.

It feels dishonest to list them all.

Answer (score 2):

I might consider using 'et int' instead of 'et al' if I were last author. A fictional names example would be:

Smith B, Jones A, Morgan R, Davies B, Jenkins P, Davies A, et int, Jones PP.

If Jones PP was whose CV it was

Answer (score 0):

If there's no one researcher among the 1,000 who stands out, no specific PIs etc. and you are John  Smith, then:

> **Insectophiliac Consortium, The [1,000 researchers including Smith, J.] (2015) Fruit Fly Buzz Demystified, J. Reckl. End. 123(45). Full author listing available at http://foo/bar.html**

... maybe even without the comment about the full author listing.